# Import default python package that was overwritten by another package with the same name

Tags: python

I'm working with a library where they thought it would be a good idea to create a module called `json` which is not at all like the standard `json` module

Is there a way of importing the default `json` module?

Comment: How are you importing the module currently?  Doing `import json` should import the standard json module unless you're doing it from code within the other library (or you execute your code with your current directory set inside the other library).

Comment: I'm trying to extend their library so I have to import json from within their library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In py2 you can use absolute importing

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import json #this imports standard lib json
import mypackage.json as my_json #import custom json module
```

Comment: Ah... I forgot about that.  Good solution.  However does it work if the 3rd party `json` is installed into `site-packages`?

Comment: If you installed a 3rd party json module, it would probably not get imported because python *usually* searches in the stdlib before going into site-packages.

Comment: My point exactly.. in that case, you can only import *one* of the two unless you work a bit harder.  And I think it searches `site-packages` first before the `stdlib` -- it searches the current directory, `sys.path`, then the python package directory.

Comment: Well, personally, any 3rd party module that has same name as stdlib module should be avoided. but yeah, if you are going to over load stdlib like gevent does, then monkey patch is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can import any module with an alias.
So if they are both named `json`, you will need to alter the import path.

```
>>> import sys
>>> hold, sys.path = sys.path, []
>>> # pop whatever json is already imported
>>> sys.modules.pop('json', None)
>>> # import json from system python
>>> import json as python_json
>>> # clean json from sys.module again
>>> del sys.modules['json']
>>> sys.path = hold
>>> # import the 3rd party json
>>> import json as thrid_json
```

If you don't remove `json` from `sys.modules`, it will still conflict on future imports (which could cause problems) but at least you'll have a handle on both of the packages in the one instance  (edited to be more explicit after @Kevin's comment).

A good workaround is to **monkeypatch** the poorly-named module.

Basically, create a module named `notjson`, and inside of the `__init__` take all the desired objects out of `third_json` and put them in the `__init__` namespace.

If you they have a package structure like this: `somepackage.json`, then you don't need to do anything special except import with `from`.

```
>>> import json as python_json
>>> from somepackage import json as third_json
```

Comment: This technique won't work.  As you correctly diagnosed, they will conflict in `sys.modules`.  Because of this conflict, later imports will return the same object as earlier imports (retrieving it from `sys.modules`).  You'll need to manually delete it from `sys.modules` to use this trick.

Comment: It does work for a one-time import, which if you put it inside of a monkeypatched module as I suggested... it should be fine.   However, you are correct in that I left out the delete from `sys.modules` explicitly above.  Correcting that now.

Comment: I can't recommend it for a one-time import either.  Someone else may have already imported the wrong version in a module that loaded before yours.  In this situation, you're basically working against the entire import machinery, which suggests to me you should just fix the installation.

Comment: Groan... that is true... unless you also pop the module before the first import.